# java.lang.ClassCastException on creating an Array of classes in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to create an array of classes and I have these:

**1)works fine**

```
Class<MyClass>[] array = (Class<MyClass>[]) new Class<?>[list.size()];
```

**2)java.lang.ClassCastException**

```
Class<MyClass>[] array = (Class<MyClass>[]) Array.newInstance(MyClass.class, list.size());
```

**3)we have a generic method , works fine**

```
public static <T> List<T> method(T arg , T[] array){
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arg.getClass(), 1);
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
    array[0] = arg;
    return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

Please explain why we get the exception in 2 ? As I understand we are doing the same thing in 3 , so what's the difference ?

UPDATE

I guess my confusion is because we have:

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< Class < MyClass > > to List< MyClass >**

```
List<MyClass> list = Utils.addToList(MyClass.class, null);
```

**Works**

```
List<Class<MyClass>> list = Utils.method(MyClass.class, null);
```

I think I'm missing something , but I'm not sure what...

So it's finally clear what exacly I had in mind:

```
List<Class<MyClass>> list = Utils.method(MyClass.class, null);

Class<MyClass>[] array2 = (Class<MyClass>[]) Array.newInstance(MyClass.class.getClass(), list.size());

List<Class<MyClass>> list2 = Utils.method(MyClass.class, list.toArray(array2));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both snippets 2 and 3 are creating a `MyClass[]`, not a `Class<MyClass>[]`.

The element type is determined by the first argument to `Array.newInstance`. If you want an array where each element is a `Class` reference, you need to pass in `Class.class`.

Note that generics and arrays don't play terribly nicely together - which is why you get a warning even for your "works fine" code.

Comment: ... and I would guess it's more likely the OP wants `MyClass[]`.

Comment: @Duncan: It's very unclear what the OP is really trying to do, to be honest. I'm just explaining their current code, and hoping that's enough to help...

Comment: I think , I understand what you mean , but I'm still confused . I updates my question , could you look?

Comment: @KatrinnaL: Well that's because you're passing a `Class<MyClass>` reference as the value of `arg`, so `T` is inferred to be `Class<MyClass>`, and you end up with a `List<MyClass>`. It's still very unclear what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot to understand what I wanted to do :)